# Eclipse not deploying my web app properly

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a base Spring project with Maven on Eclipse Kepler (with m2eclipse installed). No errors are reported by Eclipse but when I hit Run on Server (or run Maven Install) only the original files from META-INF and WEB-INF files are deployed. This does not include my dispatcher-servlet.xml config file thus causing a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
```

How can I fix this?

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is a screencap of my project's folder:

[image]

As you can see only selected files are shown in Deployed resources.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since it is a maven project .

you might have converted maven project to dynamic web project I guess.

Follow the steps

1. Go to project properties (right click at last click peoperties)
2. click/select Deployment assembly at the left side
3. the root(/) deploy path may be pointing to src/main/webapp , select this and click remove button
4. click on add button , select a directive type folder, select your WebContent folder

Now try to clean and run your application on server.

**Solution 2**

1. Actually you need to copy/put all your **WebContent** *files and folder* to src/main/webapp

and restart your server.

Note that the maven dynamic web project it always look in to src/main/webapp by default.

Hope it helps

Comment: This solved it, but if I click on Maven/update project it reverts back to original config. Also, I created this project using maven webapp archetype, shouldn't it create the expected web folder structure?

Comment: since it is created maven under webapp archetype .

So you need to put all the files&folder inside WebContent to webapp Folder.Start editing and add new files there itself remove WebContent folder .

Also make sure your (/) is always pointing to src/main/webapp

Answer (score 0):

Add `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`  in the `<build>` block.

Then Run Maven with "clean install" goal.

And refresh your project.

Now check your target folder. You should see war file or * extension file. 
Hope it will solve